# Find the limit of $c_n$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a^{*}$. Let  $c_n = max(a_n,a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}) $
Question: determine whether $c_n$ converges, and if it converges, find the limit.
What I had so far:
$\forall\epsilon>0\exists n_0>0\forall n\geq n_0 : |a_n-a^*|$ So it also holds:
$|a_{n+1}-a^*|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a_{n+2}-a^*|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So
$|a_{n+1}-a^*+a_{n+2}-a^*|\leq |a_{n+1}-a^*|+|a_{n+2}-a^*|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$. So
$|a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}-2a^*|<\epsilon$ so the limit of $c_n$ is $2a^*$.

Comment: You're on the right track but it's not necessarily true that $c_n = a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}$.

Comment: Should I maybe use the fact that because $a_n$ converges, it is also a Cauchy sequence so that $|a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}|<\epsilon$ ?

Comment: if $a_n \equiv -1 = a^*$ then $c_n = a_n = -1 ≠ 2a^*$.

Comment: Hint: For $u,v\in \mathbb{R}$, $2\max{\{u,v\}}=u+v+|u-v|$.

Comment: I just saw this in the question, I didn't notice it before, but it says $a^*>0$. Is my post correct then?